# What Opened My Excel Workbook?

Tags: excel, vbscript, automation, vba

I'm writing a whole load of VBScript to automate the processing of Excel Workbooks.

These workbooks contain VBA code which runs while the workbook is open. I need the VBA to exhibit different behaviour when a user opens it and when my script opens it.

Does anyone have any idea how I can differentiate between these two cases? (I can't edit both the VBS and the VBA)

Comment: Could you please be more specific with your trouble? Code samples will be very much helpful, in particular the parts that open / run workbook code.

Comment: What triggers the code? Is it possible to provide a wrapper around the the user-fired event call and therefore pass a flag to the method?

Comment: How do you open the Excel files? With `YourExcelApplicationObject.Open`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Test()
'This is VBA but should easily convert to vbscript...
Dim wb As Workbook

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\local files\tester.xlsm")
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    Application.Run "'" & wb.Name & "'!ThisWorkBook.IsAutomated"
    Application.Run "'" & wb.Name & "'!ThisWorkBook.Workbook_Open"

End Sub
```

In the "tester" workbook (`ThisWorkBook` code module):

```
Private m_automated As Boolean

Public Sub IsAutomated()
    m_automated = True
End Sub


Public Sub Workbook_Open()

    If m_automated Then
        MsgBox "automated"
    Else
        MsgBox "not automated"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of this... Thank you.